# change php sql results array format to json format with customized labels and values

Tags: php, json, codeigniter-3

I need help in converting this json data array

```
{"Untracked":4,"Available":3,"Groups":"4","Users":"5"}
```

to this type of json

```
[{"label":"Untracked","value":"4"},
 {"label":"Available","value":"3"},
 {"label":"Groups","value":"4"},
 {"label":"Users","value":"5"}
]
```

my method is

```
public function graphs(){
    $company_id =$this->session->userdata('itms_company_id');
    $data['Untracked'] = $this->mdl_fetch->count_untracked_assets ($company_id);
    $data['Available'] = $this->mdl_fetch->count_available_devices ($company_id);
    $data['Groups'] = $this->mdl_fetch->count_unassigned_groups($company_id);
    $data['Users'] = $this->mdl_fetch->count_unassigned_users($company_id);

    echo json_encode($data);
}
```

Comment: Why, whatever you can do with the second you can do with the first. Please explain what you are actually trying to achieve.

Comment: `echo json_encode(array($data));`

Comment: @ParthChavda Not paying attention to the question

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
public function graphs(){
    $company_id =$this->session->userdata('itms_company_id');
    $data[] = array( 'label' => 'Untracked', 'value' => $this->mdl_fetch->count_untracked_assets ($company_id));
    $data[] = array( 'label' => 'Available', 'value' => $this->mdl_fetch->count_available_devices ($company_id));
    $data[] = array( 'label' => 'Groups', 'value' => $this->mdl_fetch->count_unassigned_groups($company_id));
    $data[] = array( 'label' => 'Users', 'value' => $this->mdl_fetch->count_unassigned_users($company_id));

    echo json_encode($data);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is one way, but it seems a little long winded.

The json `{}` indicates you want an object, so you can use the simple PHP `stdClass()` and add the relevant properties and get the data from the array returned by your `mdl->fetch`'s and load the object. Then just add it to the `$data` array.

```
public function graphs(){
    $company_id = $this->session->userdata('itms_company_id');

    $d = $this->mdl_fetch->count_untracked_assets ($company_id);
    $o = new stdClass();
    $o->label = 'Untracked';
    $o->value = $d['Untracked'];
    $data[] = $o;

    $d = $this->mdl_fetch->count_available_devices ($company_id);
    $o = new stdClass();
    $o->label = 'Available';
    $o->value = $d['Available'];
    $data[] = $o;

    $d = $this->mdl_fetch->count_unassigned_groups($company_id);
    $o = new stdClass();
    $o->label = 'Groups';
    $o->value = $d['Groups'];
    $data[] = $o;

    $d = $this->mdl_fetch->count_unassigned_users($company_id);
    $o = new stdClass();
    $o->label = 'Users';
    $o->value = $d['Users'];
    $data[] = $o;

    echo json_encode($data);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

No need to change entire function.

Change from `echo json_encode($data);` to `return json_encode($data);`.

Create a function that change format from one json to another after calling a `graph()` function you can call another function that can return a json data as like you want

```
function changeFormat($js)
{
    $jsArray = json_decode($js,true);
    $result = array();
    foreach($jsArray as $key=>$value)
   {
       $result[] = array("label"=>$key,"value"=>$value);
   }
    return json_encode($result);
}

echo changeFormat($js);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here, is the example, which have same output

```
$a = array(); <br>
$a[0]['label'] = "Untracked"; <br>
$a[0]['value'] = "4"; <br>
$a[1]['label'] = "Available"; <br>
$a[1]['value'] = "3"; <br>
$a[2]['label'] = "Groups"; <br>
$a[2]['value'] = "4"; <br>
$a[3]['label'] = "Users"; <br>
$a[3]['value'] = "3"; <br>

$json= json_encode($a); <br>

<b>Output</b> <br>

[{"label":"Untracked","value":"4"},<br>{"label":"Available","value":"3"},<br>{"label":"Groups","value":"4"},<br>{"label":"Users","value":"3"}]<br>
```

So, you can write a function like this:

```
function graphs(){
    $company_id =$this->session->userdata('itms_company_id');<br>
    $data[0]["lable"] = "Untracked";<br>
    $data[0]['value'] = $this->mdl_fetch->count_untracked_assets ($company_id);<br>
    $data[1]["lable"] = "Available";<br>
    $data[1]["value"] = $this->mdl_fetch->count_available_devices ($company_id);<br>
    $data[2]["lable"] = "Groups";<br>
    $data[2]["lable"] = $this->mdl_fetch->count_unassigned_groups($company_id);<br>
    $data[3]["lable"] = "Users";<br>
    $data[3]["lable"] = $this->mdl_fetch->count_unassigned_users($company_id);<br>

    echo json_encode($data);
}
```